# What the effect after interface transition?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview, viewwilltransitiontosize

In my project there are VC and other VC as container.
I try to use `viewWillTransitionToSize` method, but after transition Interface of child VC(which is in container) isn't enable to use by touch.

I have no idea what that is the effect or problem.
Have anyone any idea about my situation?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solving this problem.
If you have same problem, check your `viewWillTransitionToSize` override  func. All actions with sizes, views, colors, location should be done along transition.
Like this:

**Swift 4.1**

```
...
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
        // there will be your handler for UI elements.
    }, completion: { (_) in 

    })
}
...
```

In my project I have UIPageVC, which exists pages (VCs). I handle transition in PageVC func for each page, besides page(VC), which is in view in the transition moment. And all works.
This is example of my code:

*MainPageViewController* class:

```
...
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
        // handlers for my PageVC

        for vc in self.orderedViewControllers {
            if vc != self.orderedViewControllers[self.currentPageIndex{
                vc.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
            }
        }

    }) { (_) in
        print("\nDONE: PAGEVC Rotated.")
    }
}
```

Maybe this code will help anyone in future.